# I am unable to install Magento on WAMP server

Tags: magento2

[image]I am following the link: "https://insync.co.in/how-to-install-magento-on-wamp-server-localhost-localcomputer/" for installtion of MAgento on WAMP server however when I click on Magento Folder It shows error. I have check all requirements for MAgento setup and it's look good.

- Apache 2.4.27
- PHP 5.6.31
- Mysql 5.7.19
- Wamp 3.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Specifically for magento 2.2 I don't believe php 5.7 is supported anymore. Its a bit confusing because magento 2 as a whole is said to support 5.6.5. Like [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html). But even the page you took a screen shot of doesn't list your version.

In your WAMP settings you should be able to change php version to a 7.0 release.

Edit - Alternatively I am running 2.1.9 on php 5.6.x server somewhere, if you need that particular version make sure you install it instead and it should work on your setup.

Edit2 - Actually your version isn't even supported by most branches. 5.6.5 is a better fit. You may also need to update WAMP to get newer versions of php available, and this may automatically change you to 7.0.x.

Comment: I tried to change the version 7.0.23 that already available in WAMP server. I get the error like: The DNS server might be having problems. I tried to solve that problem in comand promt using ipconfig/... Still it's not working.

Comment: Did you configure your hosts file and virtual host?